# how to disallow const, let, and arrow functions

Tags: eslint

We have a build process that doesn't allow `const` `let` and `() => {}`.

I want the `eslint` to catch that.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to disallow ES6 completely, or just those three?

Comment: either way is fine

Comment: doing `es6: false` doesn't solve it